# Não estou conseguindo percorrer duas listas, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Tags: python

O que eu quero é achar as raízes de um polinômio. Com isso, eu criei uma lista com os coeficientes do polinômio e outra lista com os candidatos a serem raízes. Preciso testar todos eles e encontrar as raízes. Porém não esta dando certo.

Pegando um polinômio para exemplificação: x² - 5x + 6

```
p = [6, -5, 1] #coef. do polinômio
candidatos = [-1, 1, -2, 2, -3, +3, -6, +6]

r = [] 

resultado = 0

i = 0

while i < len(candidatos) + 1:

    for coef in p:

        resultado = resultado * k[a] + coef   #Briot Ruffini

        if resultado == 0:
            r.append(k[a])

    i = i + 1

print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quem seria `k` e quem seria `a` no seu código ?

Fiz um pequeno código, espero que ajude, não usei algoritmo de Briot-Rufinni, coloquei 1/3 e 1/2, que são as raízes desse polinômio para fazer um teste. Use a bibliteca math para calcular a potencia.

```
from math import pow

p = [6, -5, 1] #coef. do polinômio
candidatos = [-1, 1, -2, 2, -3, +3, -6, +6, 1/3, 1/2]

r = list()
exponte = len(p) - 1 #pega o tamanho de p, no caso 3 e tira 1, obetendo o grau do polinomio

for i in candidatos:  #testa cada um dos candidatos
    resultado = 0 #armazenar o resultado

    for j in p: #intera dentro do polimonio com o canditato
        resultado += j*pow(i, exponte) #com o exponte você faz 6*(i)^2 e vai somando
        exponte -= 1 #na segunda interação o expoente que era 2 passa a ser 1

    if resultado == 0: #se o resultado for 0 entra nesse if
        r.append(i)

    resultado = 0 #zera o resultado para repetir o processo

print(r)
```

Comment: no lugar de k[a] considere candidatos[i]

Comment: Interessante seu código, mas não posso usar a bibliioteca math mas agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Quebrei um pouco a cabeça e implementei esse briot-rufini

```
p = [6, -5, 1] #coef. do polinômio
candidatos = [1, -2, 2, -3, +3, -6, +6, 1/3, 1/2]

raiz = list()
aux = 0

for i in candidatos:
    for j in p:
        r = j + aux
        aux = r*i
    if r == 0:
        raiz.append(i)

    r = 0
    aux = 0

print(raiz)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ficou bem simples de entender!